# Batch command backup in different folders

Tags: backup, batch-file, code, overwrite

I am trying to create a backup for assassins creed 3 save game for every x minutes , but the folder & its files overwrites every time ,please suggest me a code so that each backup will be in different folders . Sorry for bad english .

```
cls
@echo off
color 0C
echo.
echo Start Backup
echo.
pause
:start
cls
echo.
echo Backup started
echo.
xcopy "source" "destination"  /s /y /e
timeout /t 5
goto start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `time` to create a directory name:

```
set butime=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
mkdir %butime%
```

Comment: I tried it now but the problem is folders are creating on desktop

Comment: Oh sorry it worked I mistyped buttime instead of butime , thank you .

Answer (score 1):

If you wouldn't mind making the directories' names based on date and time (which I would think you probably wouldn't mind in this situation), then maybe this batch file would work. Also, this would help automate it a bit. The reason I'm making the check for if the game is running is because there isn't any real reason to make a backup when the game has been off for a while.

1. Create this batch file:

   ```
   @echo off
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
   cls
   rem Color is taken care of in the task call.

   %= ============================================================== =%
   rem * Take this section out if you want it to make backups even when
   rem * you're not playing the game.

   echo Checking if game is running...
   md "%tmp%\cmdtmp"
   set tmpdir=%tmp%\cmdtmp
   tasklist /fo csv /nh /fi "imagename eq %NameOfACExectuable%" /fi "status eq running" > "%tmpdir%\tmp.txt"
   set /p tasklist= < "%tmpdir%\tmp.txt"
   del "%tmpdir%\tmp.txt"
   rd "%tmpdir%" /s /q
   set tasklist=
   set tmpdir=

   %= ============================================================== =%

   set image=
   for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%I in (!tasklist!) do (
       set tmpvar=%%~I
       for %%J in (!tmpvar!) do if not defined image set image=%%~xJ
       rem * The file extension needs checked so image doesn't become
       rem * set with output saying that no files have been found.
       rem * This section has to be a bit complicated because there
       rem * isn't any straightforward way to get an extension out of
       rem * an environment variable.
   )
   if not defined image goto :eof

   echo.
   echo Backup has now started.

   rem * This is to ensure that the date/time format is consistent
   rem * (we likely don't use the same date/time format).
   set X=
   for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined X set X=%%x
   set datetime=!X:~0,4!!X:~4,2!!X:~6,2!_!X:~8,2!!X:~10,2!!X:~12,2!

   set bkupdir="%WhereverYouWantToMakeTheBackup%"

   md "%bkupdir%\savebackup_!datetime!"
   set thisbkupdir="%bkupdir%\savebackup_!datetime!"

   xcopy "%WhereYourACGameSaveIs%" "!thisbkupdir!" /e /y /c /q

   echo.
   echo Backup completed. Exiting...
   timeout /t 5 /nobreak
   exit
   ```
2. Create a task (there are two routes to do this):

   1. Via Task Scheduler (You probably will have the menu items translated into your native language if Microsoft has any sense at all):

      1. Type taskschd.msc in the search bar int the start menu and hit Enter.
      2. Click "Task Scheduler Library" on the left sidebar and then click "Create a new task" on the right sidebar.
      3. Type the name you want for the task.
      4. Click the "Triggers" tab and click "New..." on the bottom.
      5. Select "At task creation/modification" in the "Begin the task" drop-down menu.
      6. In the Advanced Options area, tick the box that says "Repeat task every:" with the following options:

         - X minutes (your choice here)
         - Duration: Indefinitely
      7. Click the "Actions" tab and click "New..." on the bottom.
      8. Select "Start a program" in the "Action" drop-down menu, if it isn't already selected.
      9. In the "Program/script:" box, type `%comspec% /t:0C /c "Drive:\Dir\To\YourBatchFile.bat"`.
      10. In the "Conditions" tab, make sure nothing is selected. Some of the options, if checked, will quickly and completely negate the point of all of this work, especially if you're using a laptop and both the "Start only if the computer is on AC power" and "Stop if the computer switches to battery power" are checked.
      11. Hit "OK" at the bottom to save the task.
   2. Via command line

      1. Type this into Command Prompt and hit Enter (Replace %DirToBat% with the actual directory):

         ```
         schtasks /create /tn WhatYouWantToNameYourTask" /tr "'%comspec%' /t:0C /c \"%DirToBat%\"" /sc minute /mo X
         ```

         Please note that the quotes being passed as arguments to %comspec% MUST be escaped as shown. Also, the number of minutes here are something you can more finely control than in the UI.

One item of note: The batch file is written to stop immediately after seeing that the game isn't running, and it makes the check before making any preparations to back up anything. If you don't want that, then take out the sections marked by commented equal signs: `%= ============= =%`

Also, feel free to translate the `echo` lines if you wish.